# How to display text in a textbox using jQuery and another textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, where there are three fields: Title, Slug, and URL.

I have a plugin that converts the text entered in the Title field as a slug. (For example, if I type "Joe Bloggs Goes On Holiday" would then display as "joe-bloggs-goes-on-holiday" in the slug field).

What I need to do now, is get the information in the slug field and add it to my URL field. In the URL field, there already is text (usually "/mainpage/" but this will depend on what type of page is being created). So in the URL field I would then have "/mainpage/joe-bloggs-goes-on-holiday".

How can I achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method to get and set the value of fields:

```
var urlField = $("#urlField");
urlField.val(urlField.val() + $("#slugField").val());
```

Comment: This works, but had to add another variable containing the preamble "/mainpage/". So in mine, I have added var mainpageField = $("urlField").val("/mainpage/");, and then where you have the second urlField.val() I replaced this with mainpageField.val(). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You would use either jQuery append, or concatinate the value:

**Former**

```
$('textarea').append($('slug').val());
```

**Latter**

```
$('textfield').val($('textfield').val + $('slug').val());
```

Comment: Neither of those will work. Firstly, `append` is used to add content to an element, it doesn't append to a string. Secondly, `this` in your second example is not likely to be the text field you're expecting it to be.

Comment: You are correct about `this`, that was a mistake and has been fixed. The first will work assuming he's using a textarea and trying to add to the content.

Comment: Agreed. I read the question as being `input type="text"` rather than `textarea` but it's not really clear.

Comment: James: note that you can use this if you write your code like this: `('textfield').val(function() { return $(this).val + $('slug').val(); });`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery's `val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

**HTML**

```
Slug: <input id="slug" value="joe-bloggs-goes-on-holiday" /><br />
URL: <input id="url" value="/mainpage/" /><br />
Result: <input id="result" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $urlObj = $("#url");
$("#result").val($urlObj.val() + $("#slug").val());
```

Here's [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/vkp5c/2/).

Comment: Your jsFiddle has the proper code, but is not set to an event. The code works, just the fiddle doesn't do anything, I think.

Comment: Your jsfiddle does nothing because your included library was set to mootools, use http://jsfiddle.net/vkp5c/3/

Comment: @KrisSchouw, thanks for the heads up. I updated the link - the first iteration was pulling in MooTools, not jQuery...